# Show Log From AVD

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am testing my application on an Android Virtual Device (AVD) and have noticed my app crashes after a certain button is pressed. The diolouge is `Unfortunately, myApplication has stopped.` without any option to report the crash. My question is how can I see the AVD's output to see what went wrong to fix the crash.

I also checked the Run Window during the crash, but all it said was `Application Terminated.` without providing **why** it crashed. Looking at a log file could allow me to find the bug, I just need to know where to get it. Thanks.

**AVD:** 2.7" mdpi running Android 7.1

Comment: Please read: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Look in the LogCat Monitor of the Android tab, not the Run tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to look the crash report, see in the **Logcat Window**. When your app is crash, **don't click OK**. Open the Logcat you will see the error. If you don't see any report in window, use this comment

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just fixed my crash ;p